# Can we use message api to send messages between two android smart phones?

Tags: android

I have used message api to send message between a smartphone and a smart watch. Also between one smart phone and two smart watches. Now I would like to know if this is possible between two smart phones. If yes, could you help me with the steps?

Comment: Yes you can do it.

Comment: Which api should be added while connecting to google api client?